# dhclient equivalence of 'dhcpcd -T' command

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd, dhclient

In dhcpcd, there is an option -T which is declared that:"Test case, when dhcpcd goes through the DHCP negotiation sequence but doesn't actually configure the interface."

I would like to do the same behavior with dhclient. Does anyone knows if there is any way to do that with dhclient?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not 100% clear, but the `dhclient` `-n` option *may* do what you want (from `dhclient(8)`):

> **-n** Do not configure any interfaces. Most useful combined with the -w option.

If that doesn't work, I can't see any other option than using `dhcpcd` for testing.

Comment: I had tried using -n option : dhclient -n eth0 , however it doesn't work. It just print out the usage.

Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @nick Which version of `dhclient` are you using?

Comment: This is my dhclient version: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.6

Comment: Actually, -n option can only work without any interface specified. Looks like no thing equivalence for the command 'dhcpcd -T eth0' :(